# Field with @InvocableVariable(required=false) does not is ignored by einstein bot

Tags: apex, einstein, einstein-chatbot

I have an apex class like this:

```
01    public class Example {
02        
03        public class HandleInput {
04            @InvocableVariable(required=true)
05            public String id;
06        }
07        
08        public class HandleOutput {
09            @InvocableVariable(required=false)
10            public String name;
11            
12          @InvocableVariable(required=true)
13
14            public double value;
15        }
16        
17        @InvocableMethod
18        public static List<HandleOutput> function(List<HandleInput> inputParameters){
19            String id = inputParameters.get(0).id;
20            
21            ResponseIntegration response = new SomeIntegration().call(id); 
22            
23            List<HandleOutPut> outPuts = new List<HandleOutput>();
24            HandleOutput outPut = new HandleOutput();
25            //outPut.name = response.getName();
26            outPut.confidence = response.getValue();
27            
28            outPuts.add(outPut);    
29            return outPuts;
30        }
31    }
```

In Einstein Bot, when I put action apex, calling this class, the output shows me name and value
[image]

Well, from the moment I commented line 25, and annotated the field as required=false (line 09), the Einstein bot must ignore the name field, and must KEEP the bot's `name` variable with the value it had before of this apex call, correct?

but this is not happening...
the bot is not ignoring this field, it is setting NULL for the name field... I would like the field to keep the value it had before

Comment: "required = Specifies whether the variable is required. If not specified, the default is false. The value is ignored for output variables." https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_classes_annotation_InvocableVariable.htm

Answer (score 0):

To expand Arthur's comment, the issue is that you are not setting a value for the name attribute in your output variables so we'd expect this to be null.

If you need to keep the previous value, you'll need to set the name attribute within your function. If it's no longer required, this might be as simple as null checking the 'response.getName()' value and setting it to a blank string if you don't have a name in the response.